# Rails Nested Routes path=""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am trying to create a nested route like this:

```
resources :storyboards, path: "" do
  resources :stories, path:""
end
```

This renders the following path params:

[image]

---

Because the nested route is defined *before* the parent, Rails is ignoring our `/new` route for our parent controller. I was wondering if anyone has achieved what we're trying to (using `path: ""` for nested routes)?

I believe the two fixes would be:

> 1. Create separate `new` route for `storyboards` controller (to override the other)
> 2. Somehow get rails to render the nested routes under the parent

If anyone has experience in this, your insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I did it one creating two set of routes, one for the nested child through a parent, and the other set in which the priorly nested child had its own independent paths, it worked just fine in the end.

Comment: Thanks buddy - let me test your suggestion!

Comment: code is available [here](https://github.com/arkhitech/redmine_time_invoices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from `@babar`, we managed to fix the error with a small hack:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "new", to: "storyboards#new"
resources :storyboards, path: "" do
    resources :stories
end
```